# Displaying model annotation is APS Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have uploaded a ".dwfx" file of a model into APS storage and translated it to the ".svf" format. The uploaded file has Model Based Annotations and I would like to display them in the APS Viewer.

How do I do that? Is there a parameter to set while using the model derivative api?

Answer (score 0):

The APS Viewer lets developers add labels to their models. You should try this approach.

Developers can add labels through an extension. You can find more information about this here: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/how-do-you-add-labels-forge-viewer